# python: how to insert checkbox in excel?

Tags: python, excel, checkbox

I'm trying to generate excel file row by row with xlsxwriter. In some rows I need to insert checkbox.

Does anyone knows to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try insert_button? https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html

Comment: I have read about this function. But I need checkboxes on specific cells. I don't think that macros can help because the cell names can be different in every generated workbook.

Comment: Try the function first with a simple example. I suspect a checkbox is just a particular type of button.

Comment: I found this in documentation:

Button is the only VBA Control supported by Xlsxwriter. Due to the large effort in implementation (1+ man months) it is unlikely that any other form elements will be added in the future.

Comment: Solution: I wrote VBA code to add check boxes after python has generated excel workbook. With win32com I launch VBA code directly from python.

Comment: Post it as an answer with a code snippet. Someone else could have the same question (or possibly yourself some months/years from now).

Comment: This question has come up again, in a similar form so posting the answer would be beneficial.

Comment: @QHarr check my answer :)